# How do customize the g:sortableColumn?

Tags: grails, groovy

Well, I have one column in my list that I need to customize, the thing is grails' own g:sortable doesn't work. For instance, my first column shows employee ids, then my second column, shows the employees full name where full name is a combination of first name and last name. I got it to work, sorting and all, but when I try to place it in a table with g:sortable, the g:sortable just wouldn't work. I'm thinking about passing params around but it's a bit tricky. Any suggestions?

I've looked around the internet, and seems like nothing. :\

Comment: Oh wait, never mind, looks like I found something of interest.

http://kreisa.blogspot.com/2012/05/grails-pagination-and-sorting-on-search.html

The link above is exactly what I was looking for. The author discusses about how to pass params around in the g:sortable. :D

Comment: please delete the question or create your own answer if you have solved it.